Configuración de bind-address en my.ini de MySQL para conexiones remotas
Muy buen día, he presentado un problema en que no existe en el archivo de programa de MySQL ya sea en programData o en cualquier otra parte el archivo my.ini, y necesito urgentemente configurar MySQL para conexiones remotas, por favor alguien sabe qué puedo hacer en este caso? Ya intente volviendo a instalar MySQL server ya llevo 3 intentos y en ninguno aparece my.ini

Revisa este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location

En qué sistema operativo estás corriendo mysql?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
